# NGINX Load Balancer routing to different ip if request fail

Tags: node.js, nginx, load-balancing

I have following nginx configuration for my reverse proxy load balancer.

```
upstream appserver{
    server 192.168.1.101:3800;
    server 192.168.1.102:3800;
    server 192.168.1.103:3800;
    server 192.168.1.104:3800;
}
server {
    location /api {
        proxy_pass         http://appserver;
    }
}
```

If by any chance or error my one node instance is breaking or getting restart in middle of processing request, my load balancer is redirecting the request to other ip in reverse proxy. I dont want this to happen. I want it should not redirect and respond back with 500 or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your request correctly I think you need `proxy_next_upstream off;`

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_next_upstream

Comment: @Failsal, As per docs 
normally, requests with a non-idempotent method (POST, LOCK, PATCH) are not passed to the next server if a request has been sent to an upstream server (1.9.13). I am using 1.10.1, but still POST methods are going to next upstream server.

Comment: That should not be the case. What do the access logs say?

Comment: it shows upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream. Then it moves to next upstream

Comment: Actually I want only to restrict POST methods not GET methods.

Comment: Are you able to verify that it is indeed a post request?